# how to write this sum of series in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, sum, series

how to write this summation in matlab
 if `k=1,..n`, and stored at each iteration of `k` ,i.e

[image]

> Edit

I tried to use the solution in symbolic

```
clear;clc
h=0.1; x=0:h:2;n=10;m=3;
w = @(i,j,k) (-1)^(i+j)*cos((j*pi/h)*(x-x(k)));
syms I J
J=1:m;
for k=1:n
f(k)=symsum(symsum(w(I,J,k), J, 1, I), I, 1, m);
end
```

but give me the Error

```
    Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: A square matrix is expected.
[(Dom::Matrix(Dom::ExpressionField()))::exp]

Error in sym/privBinaryOp (line 1693)
            Csym = mupadmex(op,args{1}.s, args{2}.s, varargin{:});

Error in sym/mpower (line 189)
        B = privBinaryOp(A, p, 'symobj::mpower');

Error in @(i,j,k)(-1)^(i+j)*cos((j*pi/h)*(x-x(k)))
```

Moreover, I used a alternate codes with loop condition but i don't know if it's right

```
clear;clc
h=0.1; x=0:h:2;n=10;m=3;
w = @(i,j,k) (-1)^(i+j)*cos((j*pi/h)*(x-x(k)));
    for k=1:n;
    for i = 1:m;
    for j = 1:i;
    f(k)= sum(sum(w(i,j,k) ) );
    end
    end
    end
```

Comment: You symbolic error is because you haven't defined `J` before you used it, as stated in the error. However, your second approach is more correct, you don't need symbolic operations for this. The only issue with the second approach is you're doing the sum for each `j`, but not summing for all `i`. In short, the last time `f(k)` is set is when `j=i`, not what you want which is `f(k)` as the sum for `j=1:i`. You need a running sum for `f(k)` within the inner-most loop

Comment: Please, see  above , i edited the first code

Comment: As I said in my comment, your second approach is more correct. This is a numerical computation, you don't need symbolic variables, stop developing the first method and follow my suggestion for the second method.

Comment: [Unexpected `complex` results coming in 3...2...1...](https://web.archive.org/web/20170518012317/http://stackoverflow.com:80/documentation/matlab/973/common-mistakes-and-errors/18852/the-use-of-i-or-j-as-imaginary-unit-loop-indices-or-common-variable#t=201703270859355708283)